# BuildCoreAdmin solrnetfacility is returning nullpointer exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nullpointerexception, castle-windsor, solrnet

Need to do swapping of my cores and hence need to set the SolrCoreAdmin in my solrFacility, so I can use it throughout my application using my Windsor container.

When I do the following :

```
var solrFacility = new SolrNetFacility(ConfigurationSettings.ContentSearch_Solr_ServiceBaseAddress);

            solrFacility.AddCore(AgentsIndex.IndexName, typeof(AgentsIndexMapper), ConfigurationSettings.ContentSearch_Solr_ServiceBaseAddress +"/"+ AgentsIndex.IndexName);
            solrFacility.AddCore(AgentsIndex.SwapIndexName, typeof(AgentsIndexMapper), ConfigurationSettings.ContentSearch_Solr_ServiceBaseAddress + "/" + AgentsIndex.SwapIndexName);
            solrFacility.BuildCoreAdmin(ConfigurationSettings.ContentSearch_Solr_ServiceBaseAddress);
                _WindsorContainer.AddFacility("solr", solrFacility);
```

I get following error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration.SolrNetFacility.BuildCoreAdmin(ISolrConnection conn) +40
```

I looked up the code inside BuildCoreAdmin using reflector and I think its trying to access a base.Kernel...is that null? How do I set that kernel? The base file is AbstractFacility and that has a function setKernel. What should this kernel be?

How do I solve this? im new to solrnet and need your help. Thanking you.
Regards,
Kasturi Chavan

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet

Comment: @MauricioScheffer not getting any help on forum you mentioned. i already  have a question open there.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/VA8pZyorJzc/3NypDKw4BgAJ

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. I was doing it wrong. Thought of posting the answer so it helps others.

When initilaizing the solrnetfacility , the solrcoreadmin are also initialised. I later added this solrnetfacility to my container (castle windsor in this case) so i can use it over entire application.

Later when i wanted to swap the indexes after rebuild, i just resolved it

```
ISolrCoreAdmin _ISolrCoreAdmin = c.GetContainer().Resolve<ISolrCoreAdmin>();
ResponseHeader response = _ISolrCoreAdmin.Swap(corename, othername);
```

And all set!
Hope it helps someone. Thanks a lot for all help provided.